# Yii2 Migration error - Unknown command: migrate\create Did you mean "migrate/create"?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-migrations

I am learning database migration in Yii2. I am trying to create a new migration class `create_news_table` using command through composer.

I installed composer globally and running command

```
yii migrate/create create_news_table
```

I copied this command from yii2 official site [Yii2 Db Migration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html#creating-migrations)

But after running command i got this error

```
Unknown command: migrate\create Did you mean "migrate/create"?
```

However i have written "migrate/create" not "migrate\create". Then why it is showing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writing correct syntax. But the problem was with my composer.

I updated composer using `composer update` command and now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
php yii migrate/create create_news_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `/` (slash). Try this:

```
yii migrate\/create create_news_table
```

Comment: Tried this also still same problem